# App exits automatically once it saves a .xlsx file into the phone storage

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm able to save .xlsx file into the phone storage but I've two issues.

- App exits automatically once it saves a .xlsx file into the phone storage.
- .xlsx file is saving in 'DCIM' folder, but I need to save in 'Download' folder.

  ```
  handleDownload = async () => {
  const data = this.handleDownloadAbleLogs();

  if (!data.length)
    return ToastAndroid.showWithGravity(
      "Sorry, no logs available to download.",
      ToastAndroid.LONG,
      ToastAndroid.CENTER
    );

  const ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(data);
  const wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();

  XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, "Logs");

  const wbout = XLSX.write(wb, {
    type: "base64",
    bookType: "xlsx",
  });
  const uri = `${FileSystem.cacheDirectory}logs.xlsx`;

  try {
    await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(uri, wbout, {
      encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,
    });
    console.log(uri);
    this.saveXLSXFile(uri);
    alert("Logs file has been saved in DCIM folder, do check there.");
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }};


   saveXLSXFile = async (fileUri) => {
      const { status } = await MediaLibrary.requestPermissionsAsync();
      if (status === "granted") {
        const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(fileUri);
        await MediaLibrary.createAlbumAsync("Download", asset, false);
      } else alert("We need you permission to download this file.");   
  };
  ```

Comment: Try use `await this.saveXLSXFile(uri);` instead. `saveXLSXFile` might throw but `handleDownload` will not catch it since it is not awaited which could cause your application crash.

Comment: I tried adding 'await' for this.saveXLSXFile(uri) but didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Its quite simple change the path string to '../', in most android phone Pictures and Download folders are at the same level in hierarchy so doing '../' will take one step back and save in the Download folder

```
      await MediaLibrary.createAlbumAsync("../Download", asset, false);
```